# Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, conditional-operator

How do I write an `if`-`then`-`else` statement in Python so that it fits on one line?

For example, I want a one line version of:

```
if count == N:
    count = 0
else:
    count = N + 1
```

In Objective-C, I would write this as:

```
count = count == N ? 0 : count + 1;
```

Answer (score 2532, accepted):

That's more specifically a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions) expression than an if-then, here's the python syntax

```
value_when_true if condition else value_when_false
```

**Better Example:** (thanks [Mr. Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253254/joshua-burns))

```py
'Yes' if fruit == 'Apple' else 'No'
```

**Now with assignment and contrast with if syntax**

```
fruit = 'Apple'
isApple = True if fruit == 'Apple' else False
```

**vs**

```
fruit = 'Apple'
isApple = False
if fruit == 'Apple' : isApple = True
```

Comment: It's very much like comprehensions. You can do this: `print('matched!' if re.match(r'\d{4,}', '0aa9') else "nopes")`   (assuming you import re)

Comment: Note that the shorthand syntax is only valid for actual values. You can use it with constants and functions (`Yes' if fruit == 'Apple' else print('No Apple')`), but not with keywords (`'Yes' if fruit == 'Apple' else raise Exception('No Apple')`)

Comment: It is not clear to me if I can omit else, can I just have 'Yes' if fruit == 'Apple'?

Comment: You can't omit the else when using the ternary form, it results in a syntax error, but you could do a normal if in one line , I updated the samples to illustrate.

Comment: is it possible to use parenthesis in those statements?

Comment: This answer could be benefited by contrasting this method with the same thing using a multi-line if statement.

Comment: This does not answer the original question "if/else on same line". - even though it does answer the specific example (ternary operator).

Comment: This does not work. `print(" " .join(my_list)) if my_list else print("")` returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: However it looks like you can use this format instead: `print(" " .join(my_list) if my_list else "" )`

Comment: When you haven't else statement: `when_condition_true if condition else None`

Comment: Why not this instead: isApple = fruit == 'Apple'

Comment: For a case when the value want is a boolean and can be determined by comparison, that's fine. But consider the OP scenario. count = count == N ? 0 : count + 1; That would need to be like  count = 0 if count == N else count + 1.

Comment: Can you type the first statement without the else keyword? For example, `value_when_true if condition` (without the else statement). I've tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thankss! this question was posted about 10 years ago & it helped a guy from 2021 right now & that's me!

Comment: I couldn't write something like this: `break if condition else continue`

Comment: cannot assign to conditional statement

Comment: Thought it should be mentioned that PEP8 discourages this: ["Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations). So your linter might complain (though I personally have nothing against this style).

Answer (score 298):

Moreover, you can still use the "ordinary" `if` syntax and conflate it into one line with a colon.

```
if i > 3: print("We are done.")
```

or

```
field_plural = None
if field_plural is not None: print("insert into testtable(plural) '{0}'".format(field_plural))
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this isn't the best answer?  Its definitely the easiest to read IMHO.

Comment: the question included an "else" condition

Comment: @johannes-braunias
Your method goes against PEP8 standards.

Comment: From [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

Comment: Compound statements don't run in the shell without a line after them. With the extra line you might as well split them up.

Comment: That's weird.  Here's a specific "Yes" example from [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out).    `Yes: if x == 4: print x, y; x, y = y, x`   I guess, you know, hobgoblins and whatnot.

Comment: PEP8 isn't holy writ. If your program would be better with this syntax, it's fine.

Comment: The question looks more similar to a Generator Expression than a Compound Statement. That's why the other answer was marked as the best answer. PEP8 discourages Compound Statements (although it is not strictly forbidden), but a Generator Expression would be more acceptable (see [PEP289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)).

Answer (score 170):

```
count = 0 if count == N else N+1
```

- the ternary operator. Although I'd say your solution is more readable than this.

Comment: i like your answer better, it's simple and short

Answer (score 147):

General ternary syntax:

```
value_true if <test> else value_false
```

Another way can be:

```
[value_false, value_true][<test>]
```

e.g:

```
count = [0,N+1][count==N]
```

This evaluates both branches before choosing one. To only evaluate the chosen branch:

```
[lambda: value_false, lambda: value_true][<test>]()
```

e.g.:

```
count = [lambda:0, lambda:N+1][count==N]()
```

Comment: This counts on an implementation detail that `(False, True) == (0, 1)` which I don't know is guaranteed (but didn't check). And though terse, it isn't going to win any readability awards. You can also do `"abcdefg"[i]` in C, but it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @msw: It's guaranteed that `False == 0` and `True == 1`: no implementation detail here. :)  See the 'Booleans' heading under http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Comment: But aren't both values computed, no matter what [<test>] is?

Comment: @msw: well, when it comes to ternary operations, I always prefer the first one. I just showed another possible way...

Comment: Another way: `{N: 0}.get(count, N+1)`.  A third way, if `N+1` is some expensive function: `{N: 0}.get(count, "anything truthy") and f(N)`.  This requires you to know the truthiness of the values of the dict, and they need to all have the same truthiness.  If the values are all truthy, invert the boolean operator, e.g. `{0: 7}.get(weekday, False) or f(weekday)`

Comment: count = [0,N+1][count==N]  set of given solution is not functional in python 2.7

Comment: I am straggling to understand the concept behind putting the first assignment of value if the test evaluates as false in `[value_false, value_true][<test>]` rather than the other way around (e.g. `value_true if <test> else value_false`). Is there some logic behind this seemingly non intuitive syntax?

Comment: Because `False` evaluates to `0` and `True` evaluates to `1`. Though it works, avoid it. Usually it is a _bad_ way.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why a statement like this would fail ?
`x+=1 if <condition> else y+=1`

Comment: Because the `if` syntax allows to put only _expression_; but `x+=1` is a _statement_.

Answer (score 29):

```
<execute-test-successful-condition> if <test> else <execute-test-fail-condition>
```

with your code-snippet it would become,

```
count = 0 if count == N else N + 1
```