# why is the construct  x =  (Condition and A or B) used?

Tags: python, python-3.x

One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491944/better-way-than-using-if-else-statement-in-python) is

```
print len(s)>5 and 'y' or 'n'
print(len(s)>5 and 'y' or 'n') #python3
```

if the length of `s > 5`, then `'y'` is printed otherwise `'n'` is. Please explain how/why this works. Thanks.

I understand that this is not a recommended approach but I'd like to understand why it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an old-fashioned hack.  The new way is:

```
print 'y' if len(s) > 5 else 'n'
```

The reason it works is because "A and B" will evaluate A, and if it is true, will evaluate to B.  But if A is false, it doesn't need to evaluate B.  Similarly, "C or D" will evaluate C, and if it is false, will continue on to evaluate as D.

So "A and B or C" is the same as "(A and B) or C".  If A is true, it will evaluate B.  If A is false, then "(A and B)" is false, so it will evaluate C.

As Voo points out in the comments, the value of A need not be `True` or `False`, but any expression, and will be interpreted as a boolean by Python's rules (0, None, and empty containers are false, everything else is true).

Comment: lol - my 0-point answer gets an own question - and im to late to explain it! ;-) but nice eplanation ;-)

Comment: Might be worth for completeness sake the other "hack" before the `if... else` syntax, which use to be `print {False: 'n', True: 'y'}(len(s) > 5)`(or even just `{0:'n',1:'y'}`)

Comment: Meh, there is no "completeness" of pointless hacks.  What about `'ny'[len(s) > 5]` ? The ways to abuse the language are endless.

Comment: The important thing here is that the result of `A and B` is `B` if both A and B evaluate to true and not just `True`. That's not necessarily obvious.

Comment: @Voo: actually, "A and B" will evaluate to B if A is a true-ish value, regardless of the value of B.  Try "print 1 and 0"

Comment: @Ned Never noticed that, but makes sense. For me the surprising thing when learning was that `A and B` not necessarily returns True/False (or 1/0 back then) but instead an actual value. It's actually quite the nice design imo (although not obvious to newcomers) and I actually still prefer `foo = expensive_func() or default_val` vs. the two liner with ternary if.

Comment: @Voo: I use the `x = maybe_this or that` all the time, it's a fine construct.  It's the `A and B or C` construct that is a silly hack.

Answer (score 0):

-- Logical Operators have a precedence from left to right.

-- OR operator does not check the second condition if first is True.

So your code first checks if

```
 len(s)>5 and 'y'
```

And this return True, it does not check the second condition of OR thus printing it.
Only if this becomes false the second OR condition is checked.
This prints 'n'.

For example:

```
print('a' or 'b')
#Output: a

print(False or 'b')
#Output : b
```

Thus the OR operator does not check the second condition if first is True.