# Python invalid syntax on conditional

Tags: python-2.7

I have this python code here:

```
def location(location_id, max_id=None):
        # Send http request to find location
        if (self.login_status):
            get_location = {'location_id': location_id}
            url_location_detail = self.url_location_detail % (location_id)
        try:
            get_location_id = self.i.get(url_location_detail, data=body)
            if location.status_code == 200:
               log_string = "Get location id: %d" % (location_id)
               self.write_log(log_string)

        if max_id is not None: payload['max_id'] = max_id
            try:
                res = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
                body   = res['location']
                cursor = res['location']['media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
            except: raise
            return InstagramExploreResponse(data=body, cursor=cursor)
```

When I run the program, it raises the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error seems to show up at line 447 which is the following:

```
if max_id is not None: payload['max_id'] = max_id
```

The weird thing is that the code was working before and I added some code before this line so I think the error comes from a previous line.

Unfortunately, I can't see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you need here: [Putting a simple if-then statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-statement-on-one-line)

They already explain why is this error showing and some ways to solve it

Being more clear here, you can't put what the inside the `if` in front of the `if` in python. This:

```
if max_id is not None: payload['max_id'] = max_id
```

Become this:

```
if max_id is not None:
    payload['max_id'] = max_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I've checked your link but I can't find the answer to my question. Can you raise a syntax error in my code? Because it was working find before I add some other lines and never raised the invalid syntax before.

Comment: I just edited the answer. This should be easier to see now