# Lambda function for replacing characters in the string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the Python code to replace characters. Can some explain the lambda part? Initially, X is taking "p" and checking if its a1 or a2. where is the swap happening?

---

```
def replaceUsingMapAndLambda(sent, a1, a2):
    # We create a lambda that only works if we input a1 or a2 and swaps them.
    newSent = map(lambda x: x if(x != a1 and x != a2) else a1 if x == a2 else a2, sent)
    print(newSent)
    return ''.join(newSent)


print(replaceUsingMapAndLambda("puporials toinp", "p", "t"))
```

output:

```
$python main.py
['t', 'u', 't', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', ' ', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't']
tutorials point
```

---

Thanks,
Reethika

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as :

```
def replaceUsingMapAndLambda(sent, a1, a2):
    # We create a lambda that only works if we input a1 or a2 and swaps them.
    newSent = []
    for x in sent:
        if x != a1 and x != a2:
            newSent.append(x)
        elif x == a2:
            newSent.append(a1)
        else:
            newSent.append(a2) 

    print(newSent)
    return ''.join(newSent)
```

[Lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) is a keyword to create an anonymous function and [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) applies this anonymous function to every element of the list and returns result.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any confusion, lets first extract the lambda function and see what it does. The lambda function is defined as

```
lambda x: x if(x != a1 and x != a2) else a1 if x == a2 else a2
```

A lambda statement avoids the definition of creating a named function, however any lambda function can still be defined as a normal function. This specific lambda function uses a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line). This can be expanded to a regular if-else statement. This would lead to an equivalent regular function like this

```
def func(x, a1, a2):
    if x != a1 and x != a2:
        return x
    elif x == a2:
        return a1
    else:
        return a2
```

Comment: returns a2 when x == a1 and a1 when x == a2

Comment: @CorentinLimier you are correct, I made a typo there. I fixed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It takes the String (or List) which in this case is : `"puporials toinp"`

And then it Iterates through each character/item in the string/list and checks the following: (I'll break the lambda code for you)

```
lambda x: x if(x != a1 and x != a2) else a1 if x == a2 else a2
```

1) If the char/item is not equal to a1 and not equal to a2 it map it to the same character it checked.

**Which is this piece of code: `x if(x != a1 and x != a2)`**

Else

2) it maps the value of a1 if the character equals a2 and if not it maps a2.

**Which is this piece of code: `else a1 if x == a2 else a2`**

Then the newSent is a map object which contains the chars (with the logic explained above), and converts it back to a String with the `''.join(newSent)` command.