# Jupyter Notebook / Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble to why I am getting this error. I would like to have any assistance with this issue.

```py
happyList = []
sadList = []

exclude = string.punctuation

happy_file = open("happy.txt", "r")
for word in happy_file:
    word = ''.join(ch for ch in word if ch not in exclude)
    happyList.append(word.strip().lower())
happy_file.close()
```

The error:

```
    happyList.append(word.strip().lower())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hi. it will be difficult to help you without more context, could you copy/paste the values of `happyList` and `word` just before you get this error?

Comment: added it right just now.

Comment: Thanks, you're missing a parenthesis on the line with join after `exclude`

Comment: interesting this is invalid syntax error is making me frustrated `while ans:
    user_input = input("Hello! How are you doing on this fine day?: (or press enter/escape to quit.) ")`

Comment: `user_words = user_input.split()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` user_words the "s" in words is a syntax error

Comment: FYI that's not how you iterate through the contents of a file...

Comment: I can't reproduce this, I get no syntax error. Please share a [mcve], along with the entire error message/traceback. You might find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, do note that variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

For looping the file happy_file, try using the "with" context manager to ensure you are reading properly.

```
happyList = []
with open('happy-file.txt') as f: 
    input_lines = f.readlines() 
    for i in input_lines: 
       # -- do your processing for each input_line
       happyList.append( ... )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for word in happy_file:
    word = ''.join(ch for ch in word if ch not in exclude)
    happyList.append(word.strip().lower())
```

Try putting an else case result as well when you are assigning it to 'word'. I don't remember exactly when, but I had faced a similar issue, when I forgot to give the else case for a similar assignment.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just to add why it might happen, (ch for ch in word if ch not in exclude), since this is a shorthand expression, usual way will be  to for ... :  ; then if ... : ; so because of the ':' missing it might be giving you the syntax error. But I think if you include the else part after the if, it should solve.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with a missing else statement. In fact, adding an else after the if would **lead to** a syntax error.

Comment: _Just to add why it might happen, (ch for ch in word if ch not in exclude), since this is a shorthand expression, usual way will be to for ... : ; then if ... : ; so because of the ':' missing it might be giving you the syntax error._ That isn't true either. It's a generator expression, which unlike a list comprehension, cannot really be thought of as a loop in which you append to a list.

Comment: Refer this one:
-- value_when_true if condition else value_when_false
It is actually an issue with missing else statement. Once it is added, it will solve the syntax error issue. Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802899

Comment: That link is about the conditional ternary operator though, which isn't being used here.