# python one liner suggestions for a simple If statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello i am a bit confused; 
I am trying to write this logic in one liner but i can't get it right

```
if a < 0:
  a -= 1
else:
  a += 1
```

one liner:

```
a -= 1 if a <0 else a += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do it using [`ternary operators`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/):

```
a -= 1 if a < 0 else -1
```

However, ternary expressions are not very readable. Mostly useful with `list comprehensions`. Otherwise, they just complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

The one line would look like this `a -= 1 if a < 0 else -1` or `a = a - 1 if a < 0 else a + 1` depending on your preference. This is because the `a -=` part is not changed by the if