# How to write torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu') as a full if else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, pytorch, gpu

I'm a beginner to Pytorch and wanted to type this statement as a whole if else statement:-

```py
torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the code as a whole if-else statement:

```py
torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.device('cuda')
else:
    torch.device('cpu')
```

Since you probably want to store the device for later, you might want something like this instead:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda')
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')
```

---

Here is a post and discussion about the ternary operator in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802748/13985765

From that post:

```py
value_when_true if condition else value_when_false
```