# How to write nested if-elif-else condition in one line?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a conditional check like:

```
if a > b:
    m = a
else:
    m = b
```

Then I know it could be written in one line as:

```
m = a if a > b else b
```

How to write similar one liner expression if `elif` statements are also present in conditional check? For something like:

```
if a > b:
   m = a
elif a > c:
   m = c
else:
   m = b
```

Comment: see this: https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess this question has been asked so many times in SO that's why someone downvoted the answers.

Comment: Its not by bad intention that I did the question but sometimes the title don't help that's why I did not found an equal question. Also when I was review my question this site did not ask me to look for another question that would be equal

Comment: I understand :) Try to search by keywords (not by a sentence) like this `if elif else one line python`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say if your conditional statement is like:

```
if a > b:
   m = a
elif a > c:
   m = c
else:
   m = b
```

You can put it in nested if-else in single line as:

```
m = a if a > b else (c if a > c else b)
```

In above statement you can even skip the usage of brackets `(..)`. I added it for explaining the execution order. Below code without brackets will return the same answer:

```
m = a if a > b else c if a > c else b
```

In general, for code like this:

```
if COND_1:
    m = A
elif COND_2:
    m = B
elif COND_3:
    m = C
else:
    m = D
```

You can make your one liner *nested conditional statement* as:

```
 m = A if COND_1 else (B if COND_2 else (C if COND_3 else D))
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line) answer

value_when_true if condition else value_when_false

```
'Yes' if fruit == 'Apple' else 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for elif condition we will as followed.

```
a = 34
b = 42
c = 54

m = a if a > b else (b if b > c else c) 
print(m)
```

Result: 54

Answer (score -1):

You can chain conditions just like this:

```
m = "a" if CONDITION_1 else "b" if CONDITION_2 else "c"
```