# what is the meaning of else with string statement when using python if-else ternary operator?

Tags: python

I just have a little bit confusion when I using python ternary operator. The sample code shown below:

```
a = 10
b = 5 if a < 9 else "s"
```

The else can add a string statement like 's' or '#' or ''. What is the meaning of the statement do? How to covert it as a traditional if-else statement?

Thanks

Comment: The `else` is required for ternary operators, this statement is assigning the value 5 to the variable `b` if the boolean expression `a < 9` evaluates to `True`, otherwise, the value `"s"` is assigned to `b`. It wouldn't make sense to assign a value based on a condition and not also provide a value to fall back on if the condition isn't satisified.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, if a < 9, the vale of b is 5, else the value is "s". It's the same with

```
if a < 9:
  b = 5 
else:
  b = 's'
```