# explanation for this python command in a single line

Tags: python-3.x

In a tutorial for developing a processing-plugin for QGIS  I found the following Python3-code:

```
  # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
  # get features from source
  total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
  features = source.getFeatures()
```

My question: What kind of language construct is this **single** line:

```
total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
```

This looks weird: Frist an assignment , which is followed by an if-else-construct in the same line??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)

Comment: These are called ["conditional expressions"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). From the linked documentation: "The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, `C` rather than `x`. If `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned."

Comment: thanks for your answers. Lesson learned. @zr0gravity7 if you post an short answer I can checkmark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "conditional expressions". From the [Python 3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, `C` rather than `x`. If `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned.

You can read it as "return `x` if `C` otherwise return `y`."

When a conditional expression is used in the assignment to a variable, that variable will take on the value returned by that conditional expression.

This concept is usually referred to as a "ternary" in many other languages.