# Can the += operator be used in a single line if statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I thought Python supported single line if statements but I am getting an error with `+=` on both Leetcode and Repl. The double line one works so I am here mostly to figure out the inner workings of Python.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line) I thought this would work. I would like to know if this is a Python or platform (Leetcode or Replit) issue.

Here's my [replit](https://replit.com/@thomasmb/SparklingFakeCircles#main.py) code which I have pasted below for posterity.

```py
class Solution:
    def findNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        count = 0
        
        for num in nums:
            count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0
            
        return count

nums = [12,345,2,6,7896]
s = Solution()
print(s.findNumbers(nums))
```

My error is:

```py
File "main.py", line 8
    count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You may be thinking of Perl or Ruby, both of which do actually support postfix conditionals in the exact form you just described.

Comment: Just like what you can see in the referred topic, you need the `else` here too. So it's `count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0 else 0` what you can do. `+=` needs an increment for both cases.

Comment: Why is this closed? This assumes that someone should know the ternary operator which is exactly what this question is asking.

Comment: I didn't vote for closure, but I assume it's partially about the fact that the `+=` operator has nothing to do with what this question is really about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure! Just turn that into this:

```
count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0 else 0
```

You need to finish the whole statement.

The `1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0` needs to have a determined value. Adding `0` will suffice for you, but beware, this is not always possible. Keep in mind that this is not an `if` statement, but a `ternary operator`, which are two different things.

Comment: In what cases would it not be possible?

Comment: If for example you were adding a result of a function `f`, whose argument would be your ternary operator, to `count`, where `f(x)` was never zero. The issue with this approach is that you always *must* add something to `count`, even if you don't want to. If you really wanted to use the ternary operator to inline a simple `if` statement, that's a very poor usage imho. You can inline the statement into `if cond: count += 1` if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular context, an `if` needs an `else` clause. So, you could do:

```
count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0 else 0
```

Or, if you want to be Pythonicly fancy, where booleans have integer values:

```
count += len(str(num)) % 2 == 0
```

There is a form of a single-line `if` that doesn't require an `else` clause, which is used in list expressions, like this:

```
nums = [n for n in range(100) if n % 2 == 0]
```

(yes, yes, I know you could just use a step with range, it's an example!)

Answer (score 1):

Regular assignment doesn't work either:

```
>>> count = 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    count = 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The problem is that everything on the right side of the equals needs to fully resolve to a single object before any assignment on the left side can happen. What would this object be if no object were resolved? You want conditional assignment, but both `=` and `+=` are unconditional assignment.

You could do

```
count += 1 if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0 else 0
```

but you'd be laughed out of the code review. Just let `if` be `if`:

```
if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0:
    count += 1
```