# One-line if-else in Python: interpreting behavior

Tags: python

Given the following trivial function:

```
def func(x):
     return x if True else x, x
```

Why is `func(1)` returns the tuple `(1, 1)`, even if the desired results would be the identity?

However, note that the following:

```
def func(x):
    return x if True else (x, x)
```

Does return the desired integer type.
Can anyone explain such behavior and why this happens?

Comment: A tuple is returned because your return statement has two values separated by a , - i.e. it’s a tuple, always. Might look clearer as `(x if True else x), x`

Comment: I added some parentheses: `x if True else x, x` is the same as `((x if True else x), x)`.

Comment: you are correct. So it is interpreted as `return (x if True else x), x`. Sould have noticed. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the code:

```
def func(x):
     return x if True else x, x
```

Will run in the following order:

1. `return x if True else x`
2. `x`

And with the comma separator, it becomes a tuple, example:

```
>>> 1, 1
(1, 1)
>>>
```

It's not because the condition went to the `else` statement, it's because there is no parenthesis.

If you make the else statement give `100`:

```
def func(x):
     return x if True else 100, x
```

`func(1)` will still give:

```
1, 1
```

Not:

```
100, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

below function

```
def func(x):
 return x if True else x, x
```

is same as

```
def func(x):
     return x , x
```

which return (1,1) when called as func(1). If else is useless here as the condition is always True

However the function

```
def func(x):
return x if True else (x, x)
```

is same as

```
def func1(x):
return x
```

which return 1 if called as func(1) as expected