# Python fuction similar to R's ifelse

Tags: python, r

In R there is function `ifelse(test_expression, x, y)`, does Python have smth like this?

Comment: Why ask a question and then immediately answer it?

Comment: @neuron if you figure out something that might be useful to other people, it is a useful way to record and share that information. In this case the question happens to be a duplicate, so it should get flagged as such and closed.

Answer (score 1):

With help from [this answer about a ternary form of `if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line):

```py
def ifelse(t, x, y):
   return list(map(lambda t, x, y: x if t else y, t, x, y ))
```

I don't do much Python so this may be sub-optimal/non-pythonic ...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is at least one such function from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
np.where(list > 0.8, 1, 0)
```

For example for changing list's elements based of logical expression.