# How to execute if and else in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Using python I was trying to execute if and else in a single line as below

```
expr = "no remainder" if 5% 2 == 0 else pass
print(expr)
```

output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected output:

```
It should pass condition without printing anything
```

Please help me on how to overcome the above issue

Answer (score 2):

When you use `if` and `else` in the same line what you are actually using is a **conditional ternary operator**. This is a way of selecting a value from two possible values based on a condition, not choosing whether to run a line based on a condition. So `pass` is not valid. Perhaps what you want instead is `None` or `""` or `"there is a remainder"`. Here is the correct code:

```py
expr = "no remainder" if 5% 2 == 0 else "there is a remainder"
print(expr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `pass` correctly. You should return a value in the `else` block. The pass statement is a null operation; nothing happens when it executes, so you're variable would be empty when the condition is not met. You might want to return something like `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, `pass` is not supposed to be used like this. If you want to execute the `print()` statement conditionally, do something like this:

```
expr = "no remainder" if 5 % 2 == 0 else None

if expr:
    print(expr)
```

Answer (score 0):

`s = 12 if 3 < 4 else 32`

assign 12 if 3 is less than 4,else assign 32.

[Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)