# Python if-else on one line with continue statement

Tags: python

Similar to suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line), is it possible to do the same with the continue statement?

Something like this:

```
for x in range(10):
   continue if x<5
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can do `if x < 5: continue` on one line.

Comment: No, Python does not have Perl-style statement modifiers. The question you link to talks about conditional expressions.

Comment: Are you more interested in the *syntax* in the body of the loop, or a solution to avoiding the values of `x` that match the condition in the first place? If the latter, you can use `filter` and `itertools.filterfalse` directly on the iterable to avoid entering the loop at all for "bad" values of `x`.

Comment: What *problem do you hope to solve* this way? If you simply want to know what is syntactically possible, that is what the documentation is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in `python` you will have to revert to:

```
for x in range(10):
   if x<5:
     continue
```

However, like the comments pointed out you can make a **one line if** out of that:

`if x < 5: continue`

I would not recommend using `if` statements like that tho since it makes the code harder to read and you do not really gain anything from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's one line if statements:

```py
for x in range(10):
   if x < 5: continue
   print(x)
```

as explained [here](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/#one-line-if-statements)