# Text instead of count in for loop Python

Tags: python

How to print text 'value divide by 3' instead of number?
I have a range(25,50) and I want to print all values, but if value is divide by 3, I would like to get a text instead of number.

```py
for s in range(25,50):
    print(s)
    if s % 3 == 0:
       print(f'value {s} divide by 3')
```

I would like to get in output:

```
25
26
value 27 divide by 3
28
29
value 30 divide by 3
31
32
value 33 divide by 3
```

Comment: Did you mean to make the `if` statement part of the `for` loop? Then you need to indent it as such. What specifically isn't working as you expected?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your real question is, it might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line. Or is the question about the existence of the `else` part of the `if` statement?

Answer (score 5):

Use an inline if

```py
for s in range(25,50):
    print(f'value {s} divide by 3' if s % 3 == 0 else s)
```

Comment: @PramodKumar who is learning Python 2.x at this time, it has been out of service for years

Comment: @PramodKumar Python 2 does not have a `print` function

Comment: Python 2.7.18

```python
for s in range(25,50):
    print('value ' + str(s) + ' divide by 3' if s % 3 == 0 else s)
```

Comment: @PramodKumar That is not a print function but an expression enclosed in`()` using `print`

Answer (score 2):

```py
for s in range(25, 50):
    # Check if s is divisible by 3
    if s % 3 == 0:
        print(f'value {s} divide by 3')
    else:
        # Print number otherwise
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to print all values, but if value is divide by 3, I would like to get a text instead of number. ..."*

Utilize *conditional statements* to identify the value.

```py
for s in range(25,50):
    print(f'{s} / 3 = {s / 3:.1f}', end='')
    if s % 3 == 0: print(', divisible by 3')
    else: print()
```

Output

```
25 / 3 = 8.3
26 / 3 = 8.7
27 / 3 = 9.0, divisible by 3
28 / 3 = 9.3
29 / 3 = 9.7
30 / 3 = 10.0, divisible by 3
31 / 3 = 10.3
32 / 3 = 10.7
33 / 3 = 11.0, divisible by 3
34 / 3 = 11.3
35 / 3 = 11.7
36 / 3 = 12.0, divisible by 3
37 / 3 = 12.3
38 / 3 = 12.7
39 / 3 = 13.0, divisible by 3
40 / 3 = 13.3
41 / 3 = 13.7
42 / 3 = 14.0, divisible by 3
43 / 3 = 14.3
44 / 3 = 14.7
45 / 3 = 15.0, divisible by 3
46 / 3 = 15.3
47 / 3 = 15.7
48 / 3 = 16.0, divisible by 3
49 / 3 = 16.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your answer:

```
for s in range(25,50):
    if s % 3 == 0:
        print("value "+ str(s) + " divisible by 3")
    else:
        print(s)
```

Comment: if OP uses an `f` string why use string`+`string

Comment: Just for the sake of simpler code.

Comment: it is not simpler but more BASIC like, f-strings make life easier

Comment: Do you want me to change it?

Comment: OP barely has an understanding of how indentation, for loops and if clauses work. What do you think is simpler for them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255300/discussion-between-mechanical-engineer-and-riov8).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy and more comprehensible way to do it:

```
for s in range(25, 50):
    if s%3 == 0:
        print(f"{s} is divisible by 3.")    # Print this statement if s is divisible by 3.
    else:
        print(s)                   # If s is not divisible by 3, just print s.
```